# Loop through an array of integers and break every 1000

Tags: php, loops, foreach, iteration, gpx

I am working with activity tracking files. I want to browse through a GPX file and do something for every 1000m milestone. But the device does not necessarily record a GPS track right at 1000m, 2000m, etc, so I cannot use something like `$distance % 1000`. What I want is to detect each time a 1000m milestone has passed, by performing an action at the milestone just after.

Here is an example of the distance tracked:

```
0  
3  
28 
…  
997  
1003  
1027  
…  
1998  
2006
…  
2989  
3001
```

and so on. In this example, I'd need to perform an action when 1003 has been reached, then 2006 and then 3001.

How can I trigger an event every time the data passes a multiple of 1000?

Comment: in what form you are receiving distance from the device ?

Comment: code speak louder than words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is coming in a string then you could explode the string by what ever the delimiter is and then loop it.

```
<?php
$string = "0 3 28 36 42 66 73 80 103 125 997 1003 1027 2006 3001";
$data= explode( ' ', $string );

$multiple = 1;
foreach( $data as $value )
{
  if( (int)$value > ( 1000 * $multiple ) ) 
  {
    // Passed a 1000 marker
    echo $value."\n";
    $multiple++;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1003
2006
3001
```

Comment: That exactly what I needed! It is quite simple, but I promise I pulled my hair on this. Thank you @Blinkydamo ;]
(I need to wait 3 minutes to accept your answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split a big-array into small arrays, each in the same size, you can use the [`array_chunk` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var_dump(array_chunk($ar, 2));
```

output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(3)
    [1]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
    [1]=>
    int(6)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(7)
    [1]=>
    int(8)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(9)
  }
}
```

Comment: My problem was different, but thank you for your time @Dekel

Comment: You are welcome. Next time please explain (with input/output/pseudo code) what you are trying to do

Comment: in that case, the code would have only brought confusion I guess, the problem wasn't about the code itself but about the way to do what I tried to explain.